# Quarkus Endpoints in dependency jars

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus application which has dependencies to another maven module within the same project
within that module are REST endpoints

For some strange reason i cannot access those endpoints tho.. It seems quarkus will only accept endpoints of java classes within the quarkus module, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a dummy extended class:

Lets assume your imported jar has this pattern, app\proto-gen\1.0-SNAPSHOT\proto-gen-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Add the below to application.properties,

```
quarkus.index-dependency.mygrpc.group-id=app
quarkus.index-dependency.mygrpc.artifact-id=proto-gen
```

```java
@Singleton
 MyGrpc extends XImplBase{
  //your implementation
}
```

beans you extended/implemented in your current project will be started.

Answer (score 3):

I foudn a solution:
if yopu add the jandex, endpoiints of other modules are being scanned, and can thus be found :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-index</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jandex</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference. You need to add a beans.xml to external models, create an index or reference the dependency using quarkus.index-dependency in the application.properties.

Then it will work when running tests or using the runner. But not in dev, because there is a probably in the current version (1.1.1Final). This problem has been fixed in the master, though, and will be available in the next release next month.

Please check [ClassCastException in Quarkus multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900653/classcastexception-in-quarkus-multi-module-project) for more details.